# Deleting button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Writing a school project in c++ and qt. It is supposed to be a block editor (like draw.io). I generate blocks as a buttons and setting them to a grid (code below). But when I try to delete some of the buttons, the whole window closes. What should I do to delete just only one button?

```
void MainWindow::newBlock() {
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(
                tr("SUMblock%1").arg(mainGrid->count())
                );
    QMenu *buttonMenu = new QMenu(this);
    buttonMenu->addAction(editBlockAction);
    buttonMenu->addAction(deleteBlockAct);

    button->setMenu(buttonMenu);

    mainGrid->addWidget(button, posX, posY);
}

void MainWindow::createActions() {

    deleteBlockAct = new QAction(tr("Delete block"), this);
    connect(deleteBlockAct, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::deleteBlock);
}

void MainWindow::deleteBlock() {
    this->close(); //have no idea what to put here
}
```

Comment: totally delete or just hide?

Comment: Maybe start with `auto lstButtons = findChildren<QPushButton*>();`

Comment: @codekaizer totally delete I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into using the [remove widget function from qlayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeWidget)?

Alternatively you could simply [hide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide) the button if you do not need to remove it entirely.

Naturally you need to have a pointer to the button to do either, but as I do not know how exactly you determine which Button to delete this may range from simply retaining a list of the buttons, searching for the right button via [findChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren), using [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), etc.